# Keep-alive problems in Internet Explorer 11 in a ajax application

Tags: ajax, ssl, internet-explorer-11, keep-alive

I have a web application that communicates with the server with AJAX. I am using https and SSL and keep-alive is set to 10 seconds.

Sometimes the user is sending a request to the server exactly when the keep-alive time expires. When this happens a new SSL session is created. This is all fine.
After this happens, the browser (Internet Explorer 11) is resending the AJAX request.

But now strange things happens. The browser is only sending the headers of the request. No body. The server first waits for a body that never arrives. Finally the server is aborting the request and the client gets a exception with http status 0 with message: Network error.

Some say this is normal behavior when using SSL and keep-alive and that this must be handled in the webb application. Other say this is a not correct behavior in Internet Explorer 11.

All I can see is that the server cant reuse a body of a request sent on a previous SSL session. The browser need to resend the entire request, but this is not happening.

If I catch the exception in the application and resends the request to the server, everything is working again. But it feels very strange to catch all http=0 in and resending them. Could also be dangerous from a application point of view.

The application only works in IE, so I cant compare with Chrome and FF.

My question is: Is this normal behavior or have I perhaps some incorrect configuration in the browser or on the webbserver?

Comment: Are the headers that you are getting exactly the same as you would expect (e.g. correct Content-Length)?

Comment: Yes, from a application point of view (where I work), I only see http=0 and a excpetion. The network ppl have looked at the communication i detail and have told me that it is the exact same request without a body.

Answer (score 0):

When the server closes a connection at exactly the same time as a new request on a keep alive connection was sent, then it is not clear if the server received the request and acted on it or not. Therefor only requests which are considered idempotent (i.e. not change anything on the server) should be automatically retried by the client. GET and HEAD are considered idempotent while POST not.

Thus if the client automatically retries a GET or HEAD this would be correct behavior. Retrying a POST would be bad. Resubmitting a request without a body which originally had a body (like you claim but don't prove) would be a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Right now, every request is a POST but I think I need to change that. Then I am thinking about resending GET requests. I understand that it could be dangerous to resend POST request. What I dont understand is that this resending a request after a new SSL session is something IE11 is doing without my control. So I must just accept that when this happens and I am sending a updating POST request I must abort and show a error msg in the browser.